Foreach en visual studio community 2022 versión 17.12.3
Estoy en un proyecto de c# pero las actualizaciones del VSC2022 ya no me permiten visualizar los valores asignados a la variable que se define al realizar el foreach
List<int> fibNumbers = new() { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };

foreach (int element in fibNumbers)
{
    Console.Write($"{element} ");
}

al depurar el este fragmento de código e inspeccionar el valor de element  el VS me muestra este error "threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException" en lugar del valor "0" pero cuando se ejecuta el Console.Write($"{element} "); el valor mostrado es 0
¿Alguna recomendación para corregir este error? estoy en la versión 17.12.3

Estas seguro que al reiniciar sigue pasando?? a mi no me da ningun error ese codigo... puede que se haya dañado algo en VS?

Te recomiendo que revises si no se corrompido nada de tu instalación de vsc2022, esto lo puedes hacer en el instalador de vs
